# Migrating Wagtail data between environments

Tags: wagtail, django-fixtures

I'm trying to move data from our QA servers to production (or dev->local, qa->dev, etc.) with the Django dumpdata and loaddata commands.
I've successfully got things exported that have no foreign dependencies, like so:

`python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --indent=4 snippets.somemodel`

When trying to migrate content-heavy models (with things like users, documents, images attached to them), I get lots of foreign key complaints. This is particularly problematic because users, documents, images are different across all the environments.
I would love to be able to just move the content and ignore things that depend on foreign keys - is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you copy over the complete database?

Comment: Because, the user authentication system - and images/documents are all external and different to each system. We're using oauth for users - and cloudfront/S3 for uploads. @allcaps

Comment: I hacked wagtail-transfer https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-transfer once to migrate content by forcing user constraints to adhere to a new user model.  https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail-transfer/issues/126 - the next time I do it I may polish up the process - I'm sure I'm going to have to do it again in the future.  Maybe this is helpful for you?